# Getting values from multiple fragments to activity by pressing on a submit button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-edittext

I just started shortly to programming an android app. I already searched on Google and on Stackoverflow for the answer but I couldn't find the right answer for my problem so I hope you guys can help me.

So what I have now are multiple `fragments` in a `Activity` with many `EditText` fields. When the user filled all fields, I want to get all these values by pressing on a "submit" `Button` on the `Activity`. I search for something what would recognize that I press the `Button` of the `Activity` (so out of the `fragments`) and then would save the values of all `fragments` for example with `bundles`. The best way (but I think it is not possible) would be to fetch the data by `views` of the `fragments` with `getstring`.

Can you help me?

Comment: if you click SUBMIT button you want share entered data into all fragments?

Comment: get idea about interface, call back interface from fragment on button click

Comment: No, actually I want to save all the data in a database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public interface ActivityFragmentCallback {
    String getData();
    String getTAG();
}

public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements ActivityFragmentCallback {

    @Override
    public String getData() {
        return editText.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getTAG() {
        return "FragmentA";
    }

}

public class ActivityA extends BaseActivity {
    private ActivityFragmentCallback callback;

    @Override   
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(/* your layout id */);
        View button = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String tag = callback.getTAG();
                String data = callback.getData();
                //depends on tag set your data
            }
        })
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
        try {
            callback = (ActivityFragmentCallback) fragment;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            L.e(TAG, e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        callback = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to have the "submit" Button in the activitiy instead of in every fragment, so I can't reach the way like you did it. Is there an alternative way or can I somehow find out when the button has been pressed (maybe with a callback interface)?

Comment: I like the idea..it seems to be something I would like to have. But in my fragment I got the error "Cannot return a value from a method with void result type" so I changed the 2 methods in the fragment to a string result type (public String getData() & public String getTAG())

But otherwise it is working now.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: It seems to be a problem that I can only store the data from one fragment. It is always only the fragment which lays on the right side of the actual fragment. So each time getData() and getTAG() is only called from one fragment. What can cause the problem?

Comment: do you show multiple fragments at once in one activity or you replacing fragments?

Comment: I saw that when I'm swipping to the next tab the onAttach()-Method is activated for the tab next to the actual one. I thought about to store all the fragments in a list with: List<Fragment> fragList = new ArrayList<Fragment>() and fragList.add(fragment). This is working but as soon as I swipe back to a previous tab a fragment is saved twice. I tried with if(!fragList.contains(fragment)) but the problem is that everytime it get's a new name and somehow for all the tabs with the same ID. I would like to access to the fragment class (mytabname.java). How can I do that or do you have another idea?

Comment: I need to see your activity and one of tour fragment codes

Comment: I could solve the problem. I put the callbackinterface inside of my PageAdapter where all the tabs are created (instead of onattach()) and saved them with different variables and in my activity I just accessed to these variables. So this is finally working for me!

Comment: nice! glad for you.

Comment: @PatrickVettiger could you please show me how you solved it. I have the same issue